# Gimp 2.8 (cpu not used to full capacity)

Tags: cpu-usage, gimp

Since I updated Gimp to 2.8 (and let me start by saying how happy I am with the new gimp) I have notice that Gimp only uses 35% max of my CPU power. I have tried changing settings, assigning only one CPU to Gimp (both in gimp preference and in Windows task manager). No matter what settings I choose it only uses 35% of the cpu. If I assign just one Core to it then Gimp will use 100% of that core (which is about 35% of a three core processor I have. Any thoughts?

I am using Windows 7 64 bit, gimp 2.8.0, AMD a6-3500 cpu.

When using Gimp 2.8 on my Asus A7m with an AMD Turion 64 x2 TL 50 CPU running Ubuntu 12.04 it will use almost all of the cpu power (up to 80%). And by doing so this 2004 laptop is just as fast as my desktop with the AMD A6-3500 CPU running at 35% (processing the same photo).

Any help would be great.

Comment: from what you describe, it looks like the Windows build of the GIMP isn't multithreading, while the Linux build is. wonder if one could build it from source with multithreading...

Answer (score 3):

Gimp 2.8 on Windows is multithreaded, but the filter you are using may not be.
Source: http://www.gimpusers.com/forums/gimp-user/10755-multithread